# Odoo view report through URL

Tags: report, odoo-8, qwebview, qweb

Is there an URL to preview a report. I wanna update the report_l10nvatpartnerlisting and preview it without downloading it everytyime.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what is the report you are viewing (since you are looking at the view, not the report) but you can access a report through the URL `http://<server-address:port>/report/html/<report-name>/<document-id>` for the report in HTML format or `http://<server-address:port>/report/pdf/<report-name>/<document-id>` if you want to view it in PDF format.

Example : if you want to view the sale order report of the sale.order object having the ID 38 on your local machine, that would be `http://localhost:8069/report/pdf/sale.report_saleorder/38`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this module it may help you ..

Download here : https://apps.openerp.com/apps/6.1/web_pdf_preview/

Or here : https://github.com/buke/odoo-web-pdf-preview-print

you can preview report & you don't have to download it each time